Issue with New DigiCert SSL Certificate Not Displaying on Cloudflare (Shows Old e6 Certificate)
I hope someone can help me with an SSL certificate issue I'm experiencing with my website. Here are the details:
Issue Description:
I recently installed a new DigiCert SSL certificate on my origin server. The certificate works perfectly when I pause Cloudflare, but when I resume Cloudflare, both the browser and external SSL checker tools show an old "e6" certificate instead of the new DigiCert certificate.
Steps I’ve Taken:
Set the SSL/TLS encryption mode to "Full (strict)" in Cloudflare's SSL/TLS settings.
Purged the cache in Cloudflare.
Cleared the browser cache and verified the SSL certificate using tools like SSL Labs SSL Test.
Despite these steps, the old "e6" certificate is displayed when Cloudflare is active, but the correct DigiCert certificate shows when Cloudflare is paused.
Additional Information:
The DigiCert SSL certificate is correctly installed and configured on the origin server.
The DNS settings point to the correct IP address of my server.
The SSL configuration on the server includes the necessary intermediate certificates.
Request for Help:
I need assistance to ensure that the correct DigiCert SSL certificate is displayed when Cloudflare is active. Any guidance, troubleshooting steps, or configuration tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your support.

This is not a programming question and thus is off-topic. Check the help page for webmasters to see if it is on-topic there.
